# Is this the right place to ask about finding and installing an AV?

Tags: discussion, support, scope

I know that there is some sort of Norton Open Source Antivirus for Linux, and I really want it, however I see mention and talk of it, but I can't actually find it, is this the right place to ask about where it is, how I get it, and then the installation? As I saw a question about getting Norton on Linux recently which was closed (and/or deleted as I can't find it now) because people were saying that this is something that should be discussed with Symantec and not asked about here, but as I can't find any way of contacting them about this, would it be ok to ask about this here? Or is there a better place?

Comment: When in doubt, just ask. As long as nobody throws close-votes or mod-hammers at your question, everything is fine. And if that should happen, you can still delete it and move on to the next site...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ask about software recommendations, just head over to http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com!